# How to remove SystemC startup text

Tags: text, message, startup, systemc

I wish to remove the following message at the startup of any systemc simulation: 
        "SystemC 2.3.0-ASI --- Jun 18 2013 16:21:08
        Copyright (c) 1996-2012 by all Contributors,
        ALL RIGHTS RESERVED"

Do you know where is this being done so that I can comment them?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can define environment variable `SYSTEMC_DISABLE_COPYRIGHT_MESSAGE` as 1 before you execute your SystemC application. In Bash:

```
$ # compile your systemc code
$ export SYSTEMC_DISABLE_COPYRIGHT_MESSAGE=1
$ ./a.out
```

In Csh, you can use `setenv SYSTEMC_DISABLE_COPYRIGHT_MESSAGE 1` in place of `export`.